# Check database to see if certain field already exists

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an SQL query where I am trying to find jobs that don't have a Status equal to `DEL`.
Jobs could have many statuses for example, like this job:

[image]

So I am trying to create a query to find jobs that don't contain the `DEL` status.

```
select j.*
from job_new j 
left join jobstat js on js.jobid=j.id 
where js.Status NOT IN('DEL')
Group by j.ID
```

But this query still returns jobs that have a `DEL` status. I need the query to look at each row in the `jobstat` table and check if `DEL` exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have more than one status for the same job. That's why Status not in('DEL') will show all Rows, with status != 'DEL' without regarding other rows of the same job, that have status='DEL'.

This should work for your:

```
select j.*
from job_new j
left join (select jobid, sum(if(Status='DEL',1,0)) as DEL from jobstat group by jobid having DEL=0) as js on js.jobid=j.id  
Group by j.ID
```

**We join on a prepared select from jobstat that only includes jobs that don't have Status='DEL' in any row in jobstat.**

Comment: sorry but it is still returning jobs with 'DEL'

Comment: it shouldn't. but i expected the table example to be for jobstat. What is the name of the table you posted? and could you post an example for the other table you join on?